# c++ input from csv file to a struct vector

Tags: c++, csv, vector, struct

Hi guys I'm trying to input all the comma separated text into a struct vector but for some reason the double and int values from the cdv file won't get transferred to the struct . Can you please tell me what Im doing wrong.

Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

struct dailyValues
{
    string name;
    string station_name;
    double elevation;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    int date;
    int maxPn;
    int tMax;
    int tMin;
    int observation;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("finalc++.csv");
    string temp;

    vector <dailyValues> allDays;

    dailyValues day;

    while (!infile.eof()) {
        getline(infile, day.name, ',');
        getline(infile, day.station_name, ',');
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.elevation = stod(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.latitude = stod(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.longitude = stod(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.date = stoi(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.maxPn = stoi(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.tMax = stoi(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.tMin = stoi(temp);
        getline(infile, temp, ',');
        day.observation = stoi(temp);
        allDays.push_back(day);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        cout << allDays[i].name << endl;
        cout << allDays[i].station_name << endl;

    }



    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how my cdv looks like in case you might want to see.

STATION,STATION_NAME,ELEVATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,DATE,MXPN,TMAX,TMIN,Time of Observation

GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130101,250,239,200,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130102,261,250,178,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130103,256,261,183,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130104,289,278,183,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130105,261,278,194,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130106,283,256,200,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130107,289,272,200,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130108,272,267,200,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130109,267,272,211,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130110,289,278,211,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130111,283,261,200,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130112,267,261,211,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130113,272,272,133,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130114,278,267,200,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130115,267,261,189,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130116,272,272,189,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130117,289,267,183,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130118,244,256,106,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130119,183,183,106,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130120,244,228,128,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130121,283,272,183,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130122,267,267,167,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130123,256,250,172,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130124,289,233,144,800
GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130125,250,239,144,800

Comment: Use a debugger and single step through the code.  Watch the variable `temp` to see if it has a comma.

Comment: I count 9 commas in CSV and ten commas in code. It the first record OK? and not the rest? Create a file with just one record.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - `temp` should not have a comma. The delimiter is read and discarded. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/